# ZeroMQ & Consistent Hashing

Tags: zeromq, consistent-hashing

As an exercice to familiarize myself with 0MQ, I try to code a simple
Memcached-like distributed in-memory
key-value store. The most staightforward architecture I could figure is a
OMQ device distributing requests
to backends, which are simple processes managing a data structure that store
key-value pairs.
The problem is that I want to use consistent hashing to balance the load
between the backends but
0MQ XREQ sockets use round-robin to thid end. So, is there a simple way to
use consistent hashing
instead of round-robin with XREQ sockets ?

Comment: 0MQ XREQ does no automatic routing, you'll always have to specify the target, i.e. _identity_.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a 0MQ device for federating out requests round-robin, you would need an application that has a mapping of hash values to XREQ sockets. When it receives a request, it would calculate a hash on the input, look it up in the mapping, and forward the request off to the relevant XREQ socket.